# Problem with OpenFileActivity when connecting app to Google Drive (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, google-drive-api

I am a total beginner in Kotlin. I am writing and app which shall connect to a personal Google Drive storage, lets the user pick a file and performs a certain action with this file.

In order to establish the connection to Drive I followed this tutorial: https://www.kodeco.com/5144-integrating-google-drive-in-android
At first, it worked like a charme. Unfortunately, this tutorial is rather old and my code stops working when clicking on the button that shall start the OpenFileActivity. Instead of opening the a file dialog nothing happens.

This is the code snippet:

```
/**
 * Prompts the user to select a text file using OpenFileActivity.
 *
 * @return Task that resolves with the selected item's ID.
 */
fun pickFiles(driveId: DriveId?) {
    val builder = OpenFileActivityOptions.Builder()
    if (config.mimeTypes != null) {
        builder.setMimeType(config.mimeTypes)
    } else {
        builder.setMimeType(documentMimeTypes)
    }
    if (!config.activityTitle.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        builder.setActivityTitle(config.activityTitle)
    }
    if (driveId != null) {
        builder.setActivityStartFolder(driveId)
    }
    val openOptions = builder.build()
    pickItem(openOptions)
}

  /**
     * Prompts the user to select a folder using OpenFileActivity.
     *
     * @param openOptions Filter that should be applied to the selection
     * @return Task that resolves with the selected item's ID.
     */
    private fun pickItem(openOptions: OpenFileActivityOptions) {
        val openTask = driveClient?.newOpenFileActivityIntentSender(openOptions)
        openTask?.let {
            openTask.continueWith { task ->
                ActivityCompat.startIntentSenderForResult(
                    activity, task.result, REQUEST_CODE_OPEN_ITEM,
                    null, 0, 0, 0, null
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

This code snippet is part of a class `GoogleDriveService` with arguments `private val activity: Activity` and `private val config: GoogleDriveConfig`. The function `pickFiles` is binded to a button in the activity `DriveActivity` via  `binding.start.setOnClickListener {googleDriveService.pickFiles(null)}` while `googleDriveService` is initialized via `googleDriveService = GoogleDriveService(this, config)`.

I updated all dependencies in the build.gradle but this didn't help. I also tried to debug and the code reached the line with `openTask` but nothing happened.

As I searched already a lot and could not find anything and as I am a beginner and out of options, I would appreciate any pointers that might help me. Thanks!

FYI this is a part of the dependencies of build.gradle. Maybe it helps:

```
// Google Drive
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:17.0.0"
implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.14.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.6.0'
// Kotlin
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.20"
```

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Where is the `activity` param you're passing into `startIntentSenderForResult` declared? Is this code running in an activity or a fragment?

Comment: Also minor nitpick but your kdoc comments have `@return` tags when your functions don't actually return anything

Comment: @Marsroverr Thanks for your comments! I edited the question and added the activity context. Is this sufficient? Also thanks for the hint with the doc comments. I just copied it from the tutorial.